# Using HC-08 bluetooth module with arduino

Tags: bluetooth, communication, atmega2560

I have an arduino mega 2560 and a recently purchased HC-08 module and the connection is as the following:

**Arduino** | **HC-08**

VCC - VCC

GND - GND

14TX3 - TXD

15TX3 - RXD

When I power up the arduino it shows that flashing light and I am able to see it on my android phone but would only reject the connection every time I tried to pair. Also I am not able to send or receive any data from it at all, here is my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial hc08(15,14) // RX pin, TX pin;

void setup(){
  //Initialize Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("ENTER AT Commands:");
  //Initialize Bluetooth Serial Port
  hc08.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  //Write data from HC08 to Serial Monitor
  if (hc08.available()){
    Serial.println("Reading from bluetooth");
    Serial.write(hc08.read());
  }
  
  //Write from Serial Monitor to HC08
  if (Serial.available()){
    Serial.println("Writing to bluetooth");
    hc08.write(Serial.read());
  }  
}
```

I'd really appreciate help on how to get it working.

Comment: Don't use SoftwareSerial when you're using the hardware serial pins. For TX3/RX3 use `Serial3`. In fact, on the 2560 don't use SoftwareSerial at all - there's only certain select pins it will work on.

Comment: Could you send a link to any documentation of this so I can see how to use Serial3

Comment: I've now seen I can just use Serial1, 2 or 3 just like I would use Serial. Thanks

Comment: But there still is the problem with the pairing being rejected.

Comment: But now you should be able to see and control the HC-08 through the Arduino to configure the pairing - however that's done on that board (I've never used one).

Answer (score 1):

```
void setup(){
  //Initialize Serial Monitor
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("ENTER AT Commands:");
  //Initialize Bluetooth Serial Port
  Serial3.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  //Write data from HC08 to Serial Monitor
  if (Serial3.available()){
    Serial.println("Reading from bluetooth");
    Serial.write(Serial3.read());
  }
  
  //Write from Serial Monitor to HC08
  if (Serial.available()){
    Serial.println("Writing to bluetooth");
    Serial3.write(Serial.read());
  }  
}
```

Comment: ALSO: the HC-08 uses BLE, unlike the HC-05 and HC-06 and so won't exactly connect through the phone's system bluetooth settings.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem on the hardware setting. It should be:
Arduino | HC-08

VCC - VCC

GND - GND

14RX3 - TXD

15TX3 - RXD

Variable declare:
SoftwareSerial hc08(14,15) // RX pin, TX pin;